# What (and where) is the cache.axd handler referred to in the Dynamics CRM 2015 Portal walkthroughs?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We are investigating the Developer Extensions package for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015. In [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695795.aspx), they show you how to add a CRM plugin that will invalidate your website's cached data when entities are updated within CRM.

The articles says:

> The URL to your cache invalidation will be http(s)://your-website-domain/Cache.axd.

I don't have a `Cache.axd` in my solution, nor do I have any configuration line that would map this handler to a DLL or other component in the Microsoft DLLs referenced by my solution. An HTTP request to http://mysolution/Cache.axd returns an HTTP 404.0 Not Found.

Where is `Cache.axd`? Where does it come from and how does it work? I can find no reference to it anywhere in the Dynamics CRM SDK or the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cache.axd` URL needs to be mapped to the `Microsoft.Xrm.Portal.Web.Handlers.CacheInvalidationHandler` class that's included with the CRM SDK.

The idea being that the custom portal caches data to improve performance, then when something changes in CRM you can invalidate the portal's cache using the approach described in your article above.

> ... web notification URL (from the Settings menu) that goes to the
>   cache invalidation handler of **your website** ...
>
> Cache can also be invalidated manually by recycling the application
>   pool, rebuilding the website in Microsoft Visual Studio, saving the
>   web.config file, or by adding a browser toolbar button that will hit
>   the cache invalidation handler. This will refresh the website with the
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM changes.

I happen to know this because this is the same approach AdxStudio use. This article describes the AdxStudio involvement and provides links to download the portal websites (if you havnt already). [Announcing the Customer and Partner Relationship Management Portals!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/03/08/announcing-the-customer-and-partner-relationship-management-portals.aspx).

If you are building a portal using the accelerators above then `Cache.axd` will be relevant to you. If you are just building something custom then the use and implementation of caching is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. It's in Microsoft.Xrm.Portal.Web.Handlers, and needs to be configured via your web.config file like so:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="XrmCacheInvalidationHandler" path="cache.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Xrm.Portal.Web.Handlers.CacheInvalidationHandler, Microsoft.Xrm.Portal" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

As far as I can ascertain, there is no documentation at all for this component or how it works. There's apparently a CRM Managed Solution that supports this component which will be available in the Dynamics CRM Marketplace "soon" - but no sign of it yet - so I opened up the DLL in Reflector to have a look at what it does.

To flush the entire cache, use:

```
GET /Cache.axd?Message=InvalidateAll
```

To flush a specific entity, use

```
GET /Cache.axd?EntityName=contact&Message=Update&Id={00000000-1111-2222-3333-ABCD12341234}
```

Supported `Message` values appear to be **Publish**, **Update**, **Create** and **InvalidateAll**, which I'd guess map on to the messages available when registering a custom CRM plugin.

Comment: I think the portal accelerators are quite old, e.g. been around since at least CRM 2011. So I'm not sure this is something that is currently being developed further. I think this is quite an old area of the SDK which may explain the lack of documentation.

Comment: There is a freshly-updated 2015 release of the Portal Accelerators - it's on NuGet as Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions v7.1.0.

There's even some updated documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309408.aspx - but it's somewhat sporadic and doesn't really help. For example, the discussion of cache invalidation is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695795.aspx but completely omits any mention of the required config settings or the XrmCacheInvalidationHandler component.